# PhoneGap, jQueryMobile pageinit on first page does not fire

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, page-init

I am using jQueryMobile and PhoneGap to develop a cross platform mobile app. I am binding to the first page that is loaded in the app (the 'home' page) but the pageinit event does not fire. Here's my custom javascript:

```
$('#home').live('pageinit', function()
{
    alert('firing pageinit');
}
```

Here's my index.html file with the page definition:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="home">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <a href="#refresh" data-icon="refresh" data-transition="slide" id="refresh">Refresh</a>
            <h1>MyListingsApp</h1>
            <a href="#add_listing" data-icon="plus" data-transition="slide" id="add_listing_button">Add</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" id="listings" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Filter listings...">
                <li id="hit_to_begin"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery.ui.map.full.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.map.services.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.i18n.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>

</body>
```

The event does not fire and all I get is the loaded homepage. According to the jQueryMobile docs this is proper binding to handle customization on page initialization.

Comment: probably it helps to put the links to your javascript files into the header instead of the body?

Comment: that is not required in a PhoneGap application, and per the documentation, this is the proper place, at the end of the body tag, to put the javascript files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/BGkaq/,  I made you 2 examples, you can find them at the bottom of the page.

Event binding example 1:

```
// in (url^=home) home is a page id
$(':jqmData(url^=home)').live('pagebeforecreate',function (event) {
    alert('Event has been triggered!');            
});
```

Event binding example 2:

```
$('#home').live('pagebeforecreate',function (event) {
    alert('Event has been triggered!');            
});
```

Comment: I edited your fiddle (moved the js into the js window, deleted head/meta tags), but now it does not work. Maybe this is a jsfiddle issue. I also tried wrapping the 'add listeners' into a document.ready event, but that didn't fix it either.

http://jsfiddle.net/BGkaq/12/

Comment: I think my comment pertains to an inherent jsfiddle issue

Comment: Captain obvious here! Remember [this](http://api.jquery.com/live/):"As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()."